# epoll_wait blocks for longer then timeout

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, timeout, epoll

My application waits in `epoll_wait` much longer then I specified in timeout:

```
22578 09:33:46.959791 epoll_wait(5,  <unfinished ...>
22578 09:33:50.010794 <... epoll_wait resumed> [], 128, 1498) = 0
...
22034 09:35:07.686896 epoll_wait(5,  <unfinished ...>
22034 09:35:09.482526 <... epoll_wait resumed> [{EPOLLIN, {u32=151458248, u64=151458248}}], 128, 362) = 1
...
22036 09:35:41.433241 epoll_wait(5,  <unfinished ...>
22036 09:35:43.176881 <... epoll_wait resumed> [], 128, 97) = 0
```

I have asked to timeout for one value, but timing shows that it waits for much longer interval.

Time from logs is reliable - I got it from `strace` output.
What can I do to make timeout in `epoll` more fine grained?
And why `epoll_wait` is SO MUCH inaccurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html) says:

> Note that the timeout interval will be rounded up to the system clock
>   granularity, and kernel scheduling delays mean that the blocking
>   interval may overrun by a small amount.

In other words, the timeout is a minimum value.

But such large delays do not happen when the machine is idle.
If you have real-time constraints, ensure that your code can actually run, i.e., set the appropriate scheduling policy, prevent it from being swapped out, etc.

Comment: I have skipped a lot of intermediate processing in other threads in my process. From this processing in other threads I do conclusion that I'm not in position of resource starvation. Can you give more concrete ideas how to investigate further?  The only idea I have is to investigate scheduler operations. Start from perf sched record and ... ?

Comment: Try running a 1 ms timer (with `epoll_wait`, or timerfd) in a separate thread and check its jitter.

Comment: I was able to stably reproduce issue and indeed the root cause is scheduler.